# How to run two lists of tasks with different return types at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm trying to run two lists of asynchronous tasks (with different return types) at the same time and can't quite figure out how to do so.

```
public void LoadPets()
{
    ServiceClient service = new ServiceClient();

    List<string> catNames = ...;
    List<string> dogNames = ...;

    List<Task<Cat>> catTasks = catNames.Select(x => service.GetCatAsync(x.Name));
    List<Task<Dog>> dogTasks = dogNames.Select(x => service.GetDogAsync(x.Name));

    foreach(object pet in Task.WhenAll(catTasks.Concat(dogTasks)).Result)
    {
       // Cast object
       // Do work with object.
    }
}
```

The code above doesn't work because you can't concatenate the different type of tasks. But those are the types that are returned from the web service.

I need to run them at the same time since getting the cats takes about 3 seconds and so does getting the dogs. So I end up waiting a total of 6 seconds since they happen one after the other.

Any insight on how I can run both list of tasks at the same time?

Comment: Use a common base type or interface for `Cat` and `Dog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that [`Task<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1) actually inherits from the non-generic [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) so you cast all your generic tasks to the base class, something like this:

```
var nonGenericTasks = catTasks
    .Cast<Task>()
    .Concat(dogTasks.Cast<Task>());

await Task.WhenAll(nonGenericTasks);
```

Comment: This allows me to concatenate them. But then I can't do ".Result", how do I get the results?

Comment: You just loop through the original tasks and call `.Result` on each one.

Comment: When I do that it seems to make the requests twice. The WhenAll blasts out all of the requests, just as I want. But then When I loop through the items and do x.Result it runs the request again (but synchronously this time as it loops through each item). Also I forgot to mention I'm not in an async method when doing this, so instead of await the response I do .WhenAll(...).Wait()

Comment: I figured it out. I was falling victim to deferred execution. I had to add a ToList() at the end of my select statements and then everything worked. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
 var tasks = new List<Task>()
 { 
     SomeMethod1Async(arg1, arg2),
     SomeMethod2Async(arg1)
 };

 await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

 var result1 = ((Task<Result1>)tasks[0]).Result;
 var result2 = ((Task<Result2>)tasks[1]).Result;
```

Where Result1 and Result2 are retrun types of SomeMethod1Async & SomeMethod2Async.